# Modeling non-additive seasonal variable

Tags: forecasting, econometrics, structural-equation-modeling, seasonality

Let's say I have some variable $x_{1}$ and some variable $x_{2}$ and I have the result of $y$ on a specific day/week/month/year. I believe $y$ is a random variable and its result is not very useful. What I'd like to know is what was the expectation of $y$ given my $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. How would I model that?

The variables are affected by some seasonality and are not additive. In summary, I can explicitly evaluate $y$ but I believe $\hat{y}$ is a better estimator for how I performed.

Comment: Can you explain "variables are affected by seasonality and are not additive"? Realize $x_1, x_2$ are modeling inputs so only the impact on the $y$ matters for discussion. By "not additive" do you mean that the temporal trend in the residuals of $y$ on $x_1, x_2$ reflects cyclic seasonality? Or do you mean that the trend impact in time is multiplicative and you are inspecting absolute differences among plots on a log scale? Or something else?